# Below JSTL code is not working properly .Not giving the result.It is only printing this (--select--) option value

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

```
 <select name="packageType" id="PACKAGE_TYPE" multiple>
   <option value="">--select--</option>
      <c:forEach items="${partFinderPopulateBean.filterValues['PACKAGE_TYPE']}" var="loop">
        <c:choose>
         <c:when test="${not empty partFinderSearchBean.packageTypeList}">
          <c:forEach items="${partFinderSearchBean.packageTypeList}" var="selected_flash">
            <c:if test="${selected_flash eq loop}">
            <option value="${loop}" selected="selected">${loop}</option>
            </c:if>
         </c:forEach>
       </c:when>
      <c:otherwise>
        <option value="${loop}">${loop}</option>
    </c:otherwise>
   </c:choose>
  </c:forEach>
 </select>
```

Suspecting `<c:choose>` not working properly.

Comment: "loop" var is not set or undefined. Do not expect much help if you provide hardly any context, code or description.

Comment: Updated your question.Please format question henceforth

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `${loop.index}` rather than `${loop}`

change below line in your code with this

```
<option value="${loop.index}">${loop.index}</option>
```

Please note if you use `index` it start with `0`

and if you use `count` it start with `1`